# Can an isotope also be an ion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, charge, atomic-physics, ions, isotopes

In an element when the number of neutrons differs than that of protons, it is called an isotope.
An ion is formed when an atom gains a net charge due to loss or gain of an electron.

Comment: Re: The title of your post. Why would you not  think so?

Comment: That's not what isotope means - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope

Comment: All atoms are an isotope. All can be ionized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different isotopes are different versions of an element with the same number of protons but a variable number of neutrons. An ion is an atom that has had electrons added or removed to give an overall electric charge. It is therefore obvious that any isotope of an element can be ionised, as the number of neutrons has no effect on the electronic structure of the atom.

Comment: The number of neutrons has *almost* no effect on the electronic structure of an atom.

Comment: @Buzz It slightly changes the energy levels but not the number of electrons in each, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Buzz thank you